# Как заменить буквы с тексте?

Tags: python, текст

Мне нужно заменить неправильные буква на правильные и еще учитывать слова исключения(парашют и так далее).
Была идея разбить при помощи split и дальше с этим работать, да он почему-то просто в квадратные скобки заводит. Еще была идея по индексу обратиться, но все время выдавала ошибку каким-то образом связанную с int.

```
import re
word = "абажюр"
result = re.findall(r'[жчшщ][ыюя]', word)
print("Ошибка" if len(result) else "Норма")
```

Comment: `да он почему-то просто в квадратные скобки заводит` - метод `split()` возвращает список (выглядит это как набор элементов через запятую в квадратных скобках). Чтобы обратно строку получить, нужно соединить список с помощью join: `''.join(список)`. По поводу вашей задачи, можно по идее использовать замену по регулярному выражению с помощью `re.sub`.

Comment: "чтобы заменить неправильные буквы на правильные" - это только про правописание гласных после шипящих и ц или - в целом?

Comment: только гласных.